# *cordova gradle project sync failed

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

[Build.Gradle file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3URnicCXAOJcU0zY1MxczlJMXM/view?usp=sharing)
I am very new in android development. I just installed cordova project and trying to open it in android studio. But I am getting errors saying:

```
StackOverflowError: null
```

And another error saying:

```
Gradle sync failed: Project : declares a dependency from configuration 'debugCompile' to configuration 'debug' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :CordovaLib.
```

See this screenshot for details - [Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJH66.png)

I can't run this project because of these errors.
Thank you.
Sorry for bad english.

Update: I shared the build.gradle file:

Comment: post your build.gradle. seems like you put the debug section in the wrong place